# SQL Server - Display rank of row depending on column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a query that returns:

```
RowNumber     Name
===================================
1             Invoice-02116 (1).pdf
1             Invoice-02116 (2).pdf
1             Invoice-02116.pdf
2             Invoice-02116.pdf
3             Invoice-02116.pdf
4             Invoice-02116.pdf
5             Invoice-02116.pdf
```

What I need is something like:

```
RowNumber     Name
===================================
1             Invoice-02116 (1).pdf
2             Invoice-02116 (2).pdf
3             Invoice-02116.pdf
3             Invoice-02116.pdf
3             Invoice-02116.pdf
3             Invoice-02116.pdf
3             Invoice-02116.pdf
```

More exactly, to display the rank depending on the name column.

What I am using for RowNumber column is:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ff.Name ORDER BY ff.Name) AS RowNumber, ff.Name
```

Comment: Use [`DENSE_RANK()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DENSE_RANK` instead :

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ff.Name) AS RowNumber...
```

Comment: I don't know why it's returning 1 all across the rows.
EDIT: My bad, I didn't need the partition clause.

Answer (score 2):

Use `DENSE_RANK` with an appropriate order:

```
SELECT
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY LEN(Name) DESC, Name) AS RowNumber, 
    Name
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo